# Terrain Profile starts a selected polyline-based graph in different directions

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, terrain

I´m trying to create some profile graphs with Terrain Profile in QGIS 2.10 Pisa, using LCP´s between a site and seven lithic deposits as polylines. When I select some of these lines, the graph starts counting distance/elevation points from the end of the line that is close to the site (right to left). I assume this a good behavior of the tool.
[image]

In other cases, the graph starts from left to right, creating an unrealistic profile, and making it difficult to compare properly these lines when exported individually into excel.
[image]

¿Is there a way to choose the start point of the graph provided by Terrain Profile, so I can have all the lines starting from the same end of the line?

Really don´t know what to do, maybe I'm missing something about the use of terrain profile.

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since that question but I believe it traces the profile according to the direction of the vector (the direction it was traced).

You can swap vector direction, for example by using the plugin 'Swap vector direction'.

Cheers,